# Cypress: How to perform test between my front-end react app and 3rd-party API (server) not under my control?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

What is the correct way to write E2E tests using Cypress for my front-end React app and a 3rd-party API (server) that is not under my control?

Server not been under my control, means I can't seed the DB with test data to perform a specific test.

Although, I am aware of stubbing the responses I get back from the server, I feel that an E2E test should be as close as to real life (not stubbing or mocking things).

In my case, maybe stubbing is the only way to go. I don't know, as I'm new to testing.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Beside stubbing there is another solution onboard of Cypress called 'Mocking'. In that case you feed the test the response you expect it to get. That is exactly 
the solution which we are using in our frontend to really test the application. But beside those tests we have (what we call smoke-tests) which do a real E2E test. We choose to make the E2E more like a sanity test. For example:

Our mocked test does checks for complete forms including error handling. Our smoke-tests only tests 1 happy path and 1 sad path. If those two work, we dare to conclude that all mocked tests also work in real life.